# Shipping API Call Location

Tags: shipping, api

I am wanting to dig in to what the shipping API calls send and return. Example, I want to see what magento is sending UPS and what UPS is returning.

Can someone point me in the right direction to quickly find this code? I looked in the shipping and cart modules but did not find what I was looking for.

I thought it would be here.

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request
```

However, in 1.9 it appears to be not used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own question but maybe it will help others in the future. I finally found it. I was looking in the wrong modules.

You can find this info located here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/
```